# How to configure a second IP server for shadowsocks?

Tags: centos7, vpn, vps, socks, proxy-server

I have a VPS with Default IP that configured with shadowsocks and it's working correctly. Now I need to configure the second IP server for this and show the second IP as the client IP in browser. when i changed IP in shadowsocks setting ( desktop version ) it works but the browser still show the Default IP server as client IP. what can i do? Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

If you use [shadowsocks-libev](https://github.com/shadowsocks/shadowsocks-libev/) on your server then you need to use [-b parameter](https://github.com/shadowsocks/shadowsocks-libev/blob/master/doc/ss-server.asciidoc)

> -b local_address - Specify the local address to use while this server is making **outbound** connections to remote servers on behalf of the clients.

For example if you have 2 ips 192.168.1.11 and 192.168.1.12:

```
/usr/bin/ss-server -b 192.168.1.12
```

Now you can connect to 192.168.1.11 or 192.168.1.12 and your ip will be 192.168.1.12.

If you want to use two ips and to have two outer ips at the same time you need to start two ss-server's and use combination of -b and -s.

**Example for centos systemd:**

Create file /etc/systemd/system/shadowsocks-libev@.service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Shadowsocks-libev Default Server Service %i
Documentation=man:shadowsocks-libev(8)
After=network.target network-online.target 

[Service]
Type=simple
EnvironmentFile=/etc/sysconfig/shadowsocks-libev
User=nobody
Group=nobody
LimitNOFILE=32768
ExecStart=/usr/bin/ss-server -c "$CONFFILE" -s %i -b %i -d 1.1.1.1 $DAEMON_ARGS
CapabilityBoundingSet=CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Use commands:

```
systemctl stop shadowsocks-libev
systemctl disable shadowsocks-libev

systemctl start shadowsocks-libev@192.168.1.11 shadowsocks-libev@192.168.1.12
systemctl enable shadowsocks-libev@192.168.1.11 shadowsocks-libev@192.168.1.12
```

Now you can use multiple ips without changing code just execute command:

> systemctl start shadowsocks-libev@192.168.1.13